# how to create NexmoClient object?

Tags: vonage

I tried to get NexmoClient object without success.

I Fill in API_KEY and API_SECRET with the values I copied from the Nexmo Dashboard.

```
import com.nexmo.client.NexmoClient;
import com.nexmo.client.auth.AuthMethod;
import com.nexmo.client.auth.TokenAuthMethod;
import com.nexmo.client.sms.SmsSubmissionResult;
import com.nexmo.client.sms.messages.TextMessage;

public class SendSMS {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  AuthMethod auth = new TokenAuthMethod(1111,22222);
  NexmoClient client = new NexmoClient(auth);
}
```

}
"
After the Gradle run, I was expected to  NexmoClient object as they wrote in the docs https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2017/05/03/send-sms-messages-with-java-dr/
for  continue to the next step, but I didn't know where to insert the following info

```
TextMessage message = new TextMessage(FROM_NUMBER, TO_NUMBER, "Hello from 
Nexmo!");
SmsSubmissionResult[] responses = 
client.getSmsClient().submitMessage(message);
for (SmsSubmissionResult response : responses) {
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can put that code below where you initialize the client. Your whole class will then look like this:

```
import com.nexmo.client.NexmoClient;
import com.nexmo.client.auth.AuthMethod;
import com.nexmo.client.auth.TokenAuthMethod;
import com.nexmo.client.sms.messages.TextMessage;

public class SendSMS {
    private static final String FROM_NUMBER = "";
    private static final String TO_NUMBER = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AuthMethod auth = new TokenAuthMethod(1111, 22222);
        NexmoClient client = new NexmoClient(auth);

        TextMessage message = new TextMessage(FROM_NUMBER, TO_NUMBER, "Hello from Nexmo !");
        SmsSubmissionResult[] responses = client.getSmsClient().submitMessage(message);
        for (SmsSubmissionResult response : responses) {
            System.out.println(response);
        }
    }
}
```

This blog post is actually a bit old and suggests using an older version of the server SDK. There's an updated example on the developer portal as some things have changed in the newer versions of the SDK: https://developer.nexmo.com/messaging/sms/code-snippets/send-an-sms